# Getting position in linked list from method

Tags: c++, linked-list

In this function (part of a bigger contact book program I am working on) it displays an item in a linked list, or in my case a contact. I would like to get the position of this item in the linked list, in order to delete the contact and add it back to the linked list.

```
void display_contact(std::string first, std::string last)
{
        bool found;

        node *curr = head;
        found = false;

        while (curr != NULL & !found)
        {
            if (curr->firstName == first)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else if (curr->lastName == last)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                curr = curr->next;
            }

        }
        if (found)
        {
            std::cout << "First Name: " << curr->firstName << "\n";
            std::cout << "Last Name: " << curr->lastName << "\n";
            std::cout << "Phone Number: " << curr->phoneNumber << "\n";
            std::cout << "Editing contacts is coming soon.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\n" << first << " " << last << " was not found.\n";
        }
}
```

The actual result I get right now is just the contact information (Variables from the linked list)

Comment: well the position is `curr` if you find it. What else you want?

Comment: And I would think you would want to check both first and last (assuming they are names), if(cur->first==first && cur->last==last) found=true;

Comment: For the delete method I have, it needs the position to be an `int` type.

Comment: You check matches if first OR last name is the same.  Shouldn't they both have to match?

Comment: If you need to keep track of the index, add a counter that gets incremented (similarly to how you have the `curr` pointer), it's unclear why you didn't try doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node *curr = head;
found = false;
int idx = -1;
while (curr != NULL & !found)
{
    idx++;
    ....
 }
```

if found idx has the index